# MySQL group by given an array of coulmn values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have an array `$array=array(B,c)` and a table like this:

```
id coulmn1
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 C
5 F
```

I need to group these as my given value as follows:

```
 groupby_Column  count
 group_variable   3
 A        1
 F 1
```

I need to use a group by clause for outputting the above result.

Comment: Are you sure this is a MySQL question?  It looks like you are talking about HTML tables rather than database tables.

Comment: yes i have shown u database table

Comment: Pls reformat the table to show the tabulated values instead of the html code. Pls clarify what is the meaning of the array() at the beginning.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between the input and the output. You will need to clarify this.

Comment: In the input array you have `B` and `c`, but in the output you have `A` and `F`? What is `group_variable`?

Answer (score 0):

Still not entirely clear what you want, but I'll have a go:

You have values in a php array. You want to group by on column1, but you want to treat the values in the array as one group.

In the above case you can create a query similar to the below one:

```
select case when column1 in('b','c') then 'group_variable' else column1 end as 'group',
count(id)
from table
group by case when column1 in('b','c') then 'group_variable' else column1 end
```

You can generate the in clauses from the array using implode() function.